# using Float numbers for the map's key

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

after I create a new object : `Map<Float,Integer> m = new HashMap()<Float,Integer>;`

I have an array with `"float"` numbers which are unique . I want to add these float numbers as the `m's key`! can I do this like :  `m.put(new Float(a[i]),"cat");`   ?

thanks

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend against using floating point numbers as hash map keys if possible.  Your keys must match exactly when you look up values, and it's easy to get floating point numbers that aren't exactly right.

Comment: That's why in these situations precision is being used i.e.

Answer (score 2):

Just to take all answers together.

1. The mentioned Map cannot accept strings, so you cannot say m.put(f, "cat")
2. You can but do not have to wrap float using Float: auto-boxing does it for you automatically, so you can just say m.put(a[i],"cat")
3. You are not recommended to use floating point types (Float and Double) as map key. It may cause problems when you try to extract value from map using get(key) method
4. Note also that default type for floating constants is double, not float. So, be careful with floats, use them only if you really need them. In any case use float modifier near constants like 3.14f.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a `m.put(new Float(a[i]),"cat");` because you value has to be an `Integer`. To do that you have to declare it as `Map<Float,String> m = new HashMap()<Float,String>;`.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate to given precision to generate predictable keys based on floats. An example in JavaScript

```
const precision = Math.pow(10, 4); // where 4 is number of decimal places to retain
const a = 12.5678912331; b = 13.75324122; c = 21.32112221
const key = '' + Math.floor(a * precision) + '_' + Math.floor(b * precision) + '_' + Math.floor(c * precision);
const aMap = new Map();
aMap.set(key, 'some value');
```

Useless fact: This is taken from code used to index vertices in 3d objects. By setting lower precision it allows to merge nearby vertices

Answer (score 0):

You can use Float instead of float it will convert float to an object.
i have never try it but i think it will work